# How to group twice mysql results in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this example table structure:
[image]

and I want to achieve groupped results like this:
[image]

as you can see orders are grouped first by order_id and second by advert_id

My questions is:
Do I need to group them in mysql query and how the query should looks like or all is done by php? Can you please show me short example how php code should look like. My query:

```
$query='select orderid,product_id, advert_id,qty, price    
from orders_details group by orderid';
```

Do I need to use for loop or while and how it should look like. Thanks in advance!

Comment: group by order, product_id, advert_id?

Comment: this way it returns only 1 result

Comment: actualy it doesnt returns only 1 result, but how should I loop? while loop or for loop?

Comment: This is a job for the presentation layer, not for the DAO.